# How should I convert ext4 to F2FS for main system usage?

Tags: f2fs

I was able to boot once but haven't been able to replicate a fresh install. This is a list of what I've tried and posted in hope that someone else can figure this out.

I took the shotgun approach + ended up choosing a distribution that uses Calamares as its installer. I partitioned /usr as ext4 because GRUB's files are located there and I kept running into issues with /usr as F2FS. I assume the issues came from GRUB being unable to read its files from a F2FS filesystem.

```
/boot/efi - FAT32
/usr - ext4
/ - F2FS
```

I extracted the before installing and ISO and issued these commands:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind; apt update; apt install f2fs* libf2fs* gparted -y; apt install refind
```

List of modules loaded in /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

```
crct10dif_pclmul
crc32_pclmul
libcrc32c
f2fs
```

Then saved with `update-iniramfs -u`.

Now booted into Live CD. I tried using kvpm to create logical volumes (and used mkfs.f2fs to format them as f2fs) but installation would fail to write. If it fails due to `unpackfs` then I chroot into the partitions while still in the live environment:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
. . .
chroot /mnt 
apt install refind # or apt install refind --reinstall
cp -r /usr/share/refind/refind/ /boot/efi/EFI/refind
cd /boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers_x64
curl -a http://efi.akeo.ie/downloads/efifs-1.3/x64/f2fs_x64.efi -o f2fs_x64.efi
```

Other things I've tried that failed:

- Running the whole drive as F2FS with a FAT32 boot partition failed to load OS
- Copying an ext partition to F2FS failed. GRUB 2.02 can't read F2FS UUIDs properly. Editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg to change labels to UUIDs did not help.
- Built the current branch of GRUB 2.03 and was hit with a fail when running `make check TESTS='f2fs_test'`; the list of dependencies is incomplete for novices (me).
- Partitioning root as ext4, then the rest as F2FS. GRUB's files are located in /usr.
- Tried formatting boot as NTFS to retain the ability to dual boot Windows and symlink GRUB's needed files (FAT32 can't). This did not work because NTFS is not respected as a ESP partition, flags irregardless.

References I used:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326934&p=13705533#post13705533

https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/issues/4436

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

http://efi.akeo.ie/

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-Now-Supports-F2FS

Comment: Is the last edit supposed to be an answer? It looks like the question body is no longer asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be a detail of what processes I have attempted. I'm new to AskUbuntu procedure. Should I delete my question?

Comment: I'm not sure... If you have managed to get it to boot, you could post the steps as an answer.

Comment: Right. I've got it only once but I failed to document the exact steps taken. I'll reword the edit in that case.

Comment: FAT *does* allow hardlinking, but it will show up as an error during the Windows disk check procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: You may not be able to boot into  a desktop  environment due to F2FS lack of support for selinux**, As far as a know, archlinux supoort f2fs as root partition, Fedora linux will always fail, please search before do it

First, You should create a ext4 partition of 512MB for /boot and a f2fs partition for /, I should notice you that F2FS could not shrink size, I suggest you make a partition just a few gigabytes larger then your original size

Then copy /boot and / to new location

```
# rsync -aAXv /boot /path/to/newboot/folder
# rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /path/to/newroot/folder
```

Modify new fstab file, change uuid to new partition, you could execute `blkid` to check your new partition's uuid

Execute `update-grub` to generate new boot options

If you stacked in rootfs, try use fallback img to boot

When you boot into the new system, reinstall grub by execute `grub-install`

Comment: Regarding the /boot partition being ext4, is this for MBR?

Comment: No, it is for GRUB. GRUB cannot read F2FS.